# Rspec, Capybara, selenium_chrome_headless. Wait for response after submit remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In use
Rails 6, Rspec `rspec-rails (3.9.0)`, Capybara `capybara (3.31.0)`, `selenium_chrome_headless`

I try to submit ajax form with `remote: true`. How can I wait for response?

Now works `sleep 0.2` but I really don't like approach like this.

I found another way:

```
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    loop do
      active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
      break if active == 0
    end
  end
```

but it doesn't work.

My recodr should dissapear after request:

```
expect(page).to_not have_content('User name')
```

Any suggestion? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an expectation for whatever visibly changes in the page when the request is done. If that means the text "User name" disappears from the page when the request has finished then your expectation of

```
expect(page).not_to have_content('User name')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_no_content('User name')
```

will wait until that content (same as have_text) isn't visible on the page anymore (up to Capybara.default_wait_time seconds), which would imply the request has completed. If that text is on the page multiple times and only being removed from one location then you could use a count option in `have_content` or scope your not have content expectation to the specific section of the page where the text is being removed from.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk That would do it.  Assuming you have correctly installed Capybaras Rspec matchers (require 'capybara/rspec' has occurred somewhere in your app or gems you're using) the `.to have_no_content` and .not_to have_content` should be functionally equivalent.